# How can I check what version of the VI editor I have?

Tags: vim, solaris, vi

How can I check what version of the `vi` editor I have? What's the best way to upgrade it or install `vim` on Solaris?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to http://www.vim.org/download.php, Sun Solaris Vim is included in the Companion Software: http://wwws.sun.com/software/solaris/freeware/.

vi has had the `:ve[rsion]` command going back at least as far as 1979, so it should work on any Solaris release.

Comment: `:ve` did exist in the very first vi version already, released on January 1st, 1978. See https://github.com/n-t-roff/ex-1.1 for the source code the original documentation.

Answer (score 16):

The command to show the version is

```
:version
```

which can be abbreviated to

```
:ve
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try to find the `vi` version with the package manager:

```
pkginfo | grep -i vi
```

or:

```
pkginfo '*vi*'
```

Comment: And for Solaris 11, `pkg list vim`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply open the editor by typing

```
vi
```

This will open the default page that shows the version number.

Comment: This might work for `vim` but does not work for Joy's `vi`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vi --version
```

should do this job :)

Comment: Please someone explaining what's wrong with this answer. Thanks.

Comment: On Solaris 9, `vi --version` prints `vi: illegal option -- -`.  `vim` recognizes the `--version` option; other `vi` implementations, including `nvi`, do not.

Comment: Also this answer does not address the other part of the question: upgrading or installing Vim on Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris 11 and later releases, vim is now the default version of vi.